# Imported .fbx model not showing all parts based on camera position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have .fbx model ( woman model with texture and animations included in model ) and when I open with FBX Review program or 3D Studio everything looks good ( I rotate around model and hair is always visible ). I imported model in Unity and put in scene but hair is not always visible when camera moves around ( when I move camera to lower y axis it looks bold and only part of hair is visible ) like on images below ( you can compare to see problem [image]

[image]

Comment: It looks as though the shaders have been imported with rendering mode set to transparent.

Comment: Is there lod in the model

Comment: that is a scary haircut and scary eyes

Comment: @Zze You are genius, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow on from comment;*

Recently shaders have been importing with rendering mode set to transparent, especially models generated by Mixamo Fuse.

Setting the rendering mode of the shader to opaque should solve this issue.

[image]